# Windows Server 2012, SQL Server 2012 and .NET Framework 4.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-framework, windows-server-2012, sql-server-2012

We want to start developing on the newer versions of Windows Server 2012 and SQL Server 2012. At the moment we are using Visual Studio 2010 with the .NET Framework of 4.0. We are not creating desktop apps, we are creating ASP.NET apps.

Before we spend a bunch of money on a new server and new server software, we were wondering if this can be done like this.

Can one develop apps with Visual Studio 2010 and .NET Framework 4.0 on Windows Server 2012 and SQL Server 2012?

[image: dot net inspector]

[image: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2765375 on Win 8]

Comment: Windows Server cannot install .Net Framework because 4.5 is a replacement version for 4.0 and its installed by default.

Comment: @Ramhound So what you are saying is that .NET Framework 4.5 is installed by default on server 2012, and you can't install 4.0 along side it?

Comment: You can compile your program as a 4.0 application or set the web application as 4.0...Yes I will not share my opinion though

Comment: I reopened this, but please delete your SO version now. Thanks.

Comment: @Ramhound I am not sure what you meant by "Windows Server cannot install .Net Framework because 4.5 is a replacement version for 4.0 and its installed by default" that is dead wrong. I am running Windows Sever 2012 Datacenter and I have the following .NET Frameworks installed by Windows, none which I manually installed myself. 4.5, 4.0 Full, 4.0 Client, 3.5 SP1, 3.0 SP2 and 2.0 SP2.

Comment: NET 4.5 is a inplace replacemnt to .NET Framework 4.5 that part I am not wrong about. I also know because of a problem with a third-party application, .NET Framework 4.0 cannot be installed on Windows 8. Now I could be wrong but since Windows Server 2012 is based on Windows 8 and this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2765375 I assume .NET Framework 4.0 installation would be blocked.  You sure you have .NET Framework 4.0 installed on a Windows Server 2012 installation I highly doubt it.

Comment: @Ramhound if I could leave a screen shot in the comment I would show that I have all of those installed that I listed. Also there is a huge difference in Server OS and Client OS. Windows 8 / 2012 is no exception to this. And it looks like Microsoft needs to rewrite their article.

Comment: You can leave images in a comment. You can also attach them to your question you have enough reputation.  The article is accurate.  I have personal experience in .NET Framework 4.0 being blocked from being installed.

Comment: @Ramhound also there is this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600213

Comment: @nate - That article does not apply to Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012.  The article explains how .NET Framework 4.0 can exist on Windows 7 along with .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: @Ramhound how do you attach images to comments?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes the article does apply, the problem is that you looked it up on a Windows 7 machine. I thought since you were talking so much about Windows 8 and Server 2012, that you would be using it. Please look at my screen shot, it will show what MSDN will render on a 8 OS. And to sum this up: You can have .NET Framework 4.0 installed on Server 2012, along with other versions.

Comment: @jth41 - The same way you post urls

Comment: @nate - I use Windows 8 on everything except a single machine.  I promise you I looked a the website on my Windows 8 machine also.  Neither the `Multi-Targeting Pack .NET 4.0.1` or the `Multi-Targeting Pack .NET 4.0.2` or `Multi-Targeting Pack .NET 4.0.3`can be installed on Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012.  .NET Framework 4.5 is an inplace replacment for .NET Framework 4.0.  I won't return to this thread.

Comment: @Ramhound so you have to upload your image elsewhere?

Comment: @jth41 Add your image to an answer, grab the URL it uses, post the url in a comment, click "discard" on the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, one can develop apps with Visual Studio 2010 and .NET Framework 4.0 on Windows Server 2012 and SQL Server 2012. There are no known problems with that combination.

Comment: as long as you dont use .NET 4.5 components, you wont have issues.

Comment: Well, one problem is if you are trying to debug a memory dump from a 4.0 system on your 4.5 system it wont work. Due to the BCL not matching version numbers.